# ESP32 Consistently Restarting after Closing Serial Connection

Tags: arduino, serial-port, microcontroller, esp32, data-transfer

I'm pretty new to microcontroller stuff and have some limited programming experience, but I cannot figure out why my ESP is restarting after I finish transferring some data over USB from my python script (PC) to my ESP32.

I made a very simple program using Serial Transfer library for both sending ([PySerialTransfer](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/pySerialTransfer/blob/master/pySerialTransfer/pySerialTransfer.py)) and recieving ([SerialTransfer](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/SerialTransfer/blob/master/src/SerialTransfer.h)). These two libraries are compatible with each other. I am using my LCD to tell when it restarts (since I can't use Serial monitor for debugging, the com port is being used).

**ESP CODE**

```
#include "SerialTransfer.h"
#include "SPI.h"
#include <TFT_eSPI.h>              // Hardware-specific library
TFT_eSPI tft = TFT_eSPI();     

SerialTransfer myTransfer;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myTransfer.begin(Serial);

  tft.begin();
  tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLACK);
}


void loop()
{
  if(myTransfer.available())
  {
    tft.fillScreen(TFT_BLUE);
  }
}
```

**PYTHON CODE**

```
import time
from pySerialTransfer import pySerialTransfer as txfer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    link = txfer.SerialTransfer('COM4')

    link.open()

    float = 5.234
    float_size = link.tx_obj(float)  # pack float into output buffer

    link.send(float_size)

    time.sleep(2)  # sleep allows time to see color change before restart

    link.close()
```

**Problem**

When I run my Python code, I expect my screen to turn from black to blue and stay blue, even after the connection is closed. Instead what I get is my screen turning blue for 2 seconds and then my ESP immediately restarting (screen flashes white and returns to black). If I place the code

```
    float = 5.234
    float_size = link.tx_obj(float)  # pack float into output buffer

    link.send(float_size)
```

from my python script into a while True: loop, the screen remains blue forever. It seems to me that the failing point is `link.close()` in my python script. If I remove that, it still restarts at the termination of the python script anyways. I don't understand if this is intended behavior or not. My goal is to occasionally connect to my ESP while it is running, send it a large list of data from my PC, and display it on screen, without any restarts.
This kind of behavior is the same in my larger scripts of the same nature. My ESP will recieve all of the data fine and perform its operations successfully, but once my python script closes the serial connection, the ESP restarts.

Also sidenote, I don't know if using USB is ideal for this kind of goal, or if I should use bluetooth or wifi. I intend for this to be connected to my PC and powered 24/7 via USB so I assume USB would be easiest to transfer data.

Comment: "_as soon as the stream of data stops from python, the ESP restarts_" is not what you observe. You mention the delay of 2 seconds without any data. Instead, as the (virtual) serial connection is closed, the ESP restarts. -- Did you try to use a terminal program (Teraterm, PuTTY, ...) in place of your Python script? -- On your side note, USB is perfect. -- It seems to be the `SerialTransfer` object that perhaps crashes. Would you mind to link to relevant documentation?

Comment: No I havent tried using a terminal, I've been using PyCharm but I can try later this afternoon. Ive provided a link to the header file of SerialTransfer library. The comments in there seem to be the only documentation. I noticed some example scripts provided for sending data in the github, I will try those and see if they crash as well with the appropriate esp reciever examples.

Comment: After reading the introduction of the library, I'm afraid that you cannot comfortably use a terminal. The underlying protocol puts a frame around your payload, which is hard to mock. -- You might want to consider to use the serial interface without such a protocol. -- However, the open-close issue can be checked with a terminal program.

Comment: Perhaps there is a watchdog that enabled by default, not getting fed, and causing a reset after two seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to disable DTR/RTS in my PC python script like so (using pyserial) in order to stop my ESP from restarting, I can't use the SerialTransfer library for this anymore so I will have to rewrite everything but at least it works

```
link = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200, dsrdtr=None)
link.setRTS(False)
link.setDTR(False)
```